# Как подправить xml файл координатора в hadoop?

Tags: xml, hadoop

Вопрос в том, как запускать координатор только тогда, когда в определённой (/user/task/) папке существует, например, файл под именем "_SUCCESS"? Содержание coordinator.xml следующее:

```
   <coordinator-app name="My_Coordinator"
  frequency="0 0 * * *"
  start="${start_date}" end="${end_date}" timezone="America/Los_Angeles"
  xmlns="uri:oozie:coordinator:0.2"
  >
  <controls>
    <execution>FIFO</execution>
  </controls>
  <action>
    <workflow>
      <app-path>${wf_application_path}</app-path>
      <configuration>
        <property>
          <name>oozie.use.system.libpath</name>
          <value>True</value>
        </property>
        <property>
          <name>start_date</name>
          <value>2015-11-09T22:46Z</value>
        </property>
        <property>
          <name>end_date</name>
          <value>2015-11-16T22:46Z</value>
        </property>
      </configuration>
   </workflow>
  </action>
</coordinator-app>
```

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 1):

Например, после `<coordinator-app`.... добавить:

```
<datasets>
   <dataset name="ds_input1" frequency="${coord:hours(6)}" initial-instance="${start_date}">
      <uri-template>
         hdfs://localhost:8020/user/task
      </uri-template>
   <done-flag>_SUCCESS</done-flag>
   </dataset>
</datasets>
```

Это шаблон, который будет генерироваться каждые 6 часов. Есть возможность использовать константы YEAR, MONTH, DAY .. в `<uri-template>`

Затем надо создать событие, на появление данного шаблона в вашей файловой системе. Данный блок разместите после `</datasets>`

```
<input-events>
   <data-in name="event_input1" dataset="ds_input1">
      <instance>${coord:current(0)}</instance>
   </data-in>
</input-events>
```

Затем можно добавить свойство, через которое можно получать путь к данным

```
<property>
   <name>myInputDirs</name>
   <value>${coord:dataIn('event_input1')}</value>
</property>
```